# Getting null values on attributes of inner class

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following KnockoutJS mapping using inner classes:

```
public class Retailer
{
    public int RetailerId { get; set; }
    public string DemoNumber { get; set; }
    public string OutletName { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Logging Logging { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string LandLine { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The above shows my model, I'm building my website using KnockoutJS.

I'm able to bind the controls using the `ko.mapping` plugin. However, when I try to insert the values of Retailer, the inner class `Address` is returning `null` values for all the attributes.

When I test things client side it's showing entire model values.

```
IdeaSales.NewRetailer = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Retailer/Retailer',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
}

IdeaSales.InsertRetailer = function () {
    var newModel = ko.toJS(viewModel);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Retailer/InsertRetailer',
        data:viewModel,
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

And:

```
public int InsertRetailer(Retailer retailer)
{
    return new RetailerAppService().InsertRetailer(retailer);
}
```

The problem is I'm getting retailer information, but for Address class I'm getting `Null` values for each.

Comment: You are posting `data:viewModel`, didn't you intend to post `data:newModel`? In any case, it would help if you inspect that POST and see what's being sent to the server: is it what you expect?

Comment: The MVC model binding will initialize all parameters in the action, and then attempt to bind values posted with the object posted. The default value of address in retailer is null when it is constructed, and like jeroen said, you look to be passing the wrong value in the post anyway, so retailer will just be default values for everything.

Comment: Ok!! But while passing model to server, I can able to pass the retailer information, but the address information is null

Answer (score 1):

As you are sending JSON to the server, you need to specify the
    contentType.

This version of InsertRetailer should work:

```
IdeaSales.InsertRetailer = function () {
    var newModel = ko.toJS(viewModel);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Retailer/InsertRetailer',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: newModel,
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```